# JavaScript Templating Trick or Treat?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, templating

I've recently been looking into using JavaScript for templating and I was wondering about the legibility of using this approach.

I understand that JavaScript templating is a very common and much accepted form of templating and I do see the benefits of using this technique.

My question stems more from curiosity as storing HTML text inside a script breaks away from what a 'script' actually is, so to me it feels *wrong* to do this.

**Was JavaScript originally designed to be used as a templating technique when the browser does not understand the type of script? Or was it a trick that people discovered and began to use as HTML text holders for templating purposes?**

**UPDATE**

I understand that my question may be more opinion based, so my updated question:

I've read that unknown scripts are not processed as scripts and are left as text blocks **because** of compatibility reasons - so newer browsers can support additional languages without older browsers breaking.

This may sound opinionated to some, but I'm not after opinions, I'm trying to understand **why** browsers behave in the way they do when unknown scripts are found/the intention behind this behaviour.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad after the edit. Such a topic belongs more on Programmers.StackExchange than on Stack Overflow, since it's asking for design philosophy.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll go there :)

Comment: Do make sure you check out their "Tour" page to make sure your question fits! (e.g. don't just copy and paste this one)

Comment: You might find this useful: https://medium.com/@housecor/react-s-jsx-the-other-side-of-the-coin-2ace7ab62b98#.clm5fpqt5

Answer (score 1):

> Was JavaScript originally designed to be used as a templating technique when the browser does not understand the type of script?

No. JavaScript was originally designed to bring simple scripting to the browser.

> I understand that JavaScript templating is a very common and much accepted form of templating

JavaScript isn't a templating language. However, what you are seeing are *templating libraries* that are *written in* JavaScript.

Comment: If JavaScript was only intended to bring scripting to the browser, then how long ago did people discover that JavaScript can be manipulated for templation purposes?